# Legends display order in piechart highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Can we display legends below the chart based on percentage(%) values in descending order dynamically like shown in below example ?  In below example values are hardcoded (chrome, internal explorer etc..) . In real time values will come from database. So i want to know if these values in the legends can be displayed dynamically in an order based on % values ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/pie-chart-using-highcharts

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `afterGetAllItems` Highcharts event and sort legend items depending on `y` value.

Example:

```
(function(H) {
    H.addEvent(H.Legend, 'afterGetAllItems', function(e) {
        e.allItems = e.allItems.sort((p1, p2) => p2.y - p1.y);
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9c753pwx/

**API Reference:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Thank you very much. I will check and get back to you on this.